# how does memory account for different "occurrences" of the same variable?

Tags: python, pointers, variables, memory

Let's assume I have the following:

```
class Object():
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  
object = Object()

mylist = [object,[object]]
```

How can the memory distinguish between the "outtermost" Object object and the one that is inside the embedded list? Because, if I print the memory address of these two elements, I get the same:

```
def iter_and_print_id(element):
  for e in element:
    if isinstance(e,list):
      iter_and_print_id(e)
    else:
      print(id(e))

iter_and_print_id(mylist)
# 132270543332992
# 132270543332992
```

I know that they have different indices: `mylist[0]` and `mylist[1][0]`, but does this have any reflection on the way the memory stores these variables or, more precisely, these occurences of the same variable?

At the same time, would `mylist` occupy more space if it contained three occurrences rather than two? Things like `[object,object,object]`, for example, or whatever. If so, why? Considering that the variables point to the same memory address.

And, finally, how to explain this?

```
[1] == [1,1] # False
id([1]) == id([1,1]) # True
```

Maybe I'm a little misguided.

Comment: `object` is just a reference to your `Object` instance. In memory it's just a number pointing to the piece of memory that actually holds `object`. Therefore it's no different to a list that is `[1, [1]]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so, thanks! But I still can't grasp this: why something like [1,1,1] would be heavier in memory than [1,1] if the objects inside the lists point to the same memory address?

Comment: There may only be one object in memory, but you still need to store X number of pointers where X is the size of your list.

Comment: Well, in that case, would every occurrence of 1 have its own pointer (with its own specific address)? How do I get it?

Comment: We're getting a bit in the weeds now. Note there is a difference between `1`, representing a memory address, and `1` an integer object in Python. In my first comment I didn't mean it would be a list of Python integers (which would have their own memory address), I just meant it would be a list of actual numbers. I suspect this might be getting a bit off topic and confusing now. To answer your question, no, each pointer doesn't have its own pointer.

Comment: And to answer your edit: I suspect it's just scoping. `[1] == [1,1]` needs to have both lists existing at the same time, so it needs two different memory addresses. `id([1]) == id([1,1])` after the first `id` call it can throw the list away, then it creates the second list in the same memory location, therefore the ids are equal.

Comment: Sorry, this is my last question, just to clarify. If I have something like:

`one = 1`
`one_ = 1`

The difference between `[one,one_]` and `[1,1]` is that the first list has two variables, each pointing to the same address, that have, at the same time, an specific address for them as a pointer. So we'd have 5 addresses (including the list). In the second list, instead, we have only two. Right? 

But this "method" doesn't work if I want to explain why `[1,1]` occupies less space than `[1,1,1]`. So, in memory, how would I represent the former and the latter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255239/discussion-between-invalid-syntax-and-loocid).