# Which object takes up more memory space and why: [1] or [1,1]?

Tags: memory, memory-management, reference, copy

Let's assume I have two list in Python: `a = [1]` and `b = [1,1]` (the language is irrelevant, as well as the object inside the lists).

My question is: which of them takes up more memory space, and why? This question arises because, as far as I know, both lists contain objects with the same memory address: `id(b[0]) == id(b[1]) # True`. So, where would this difference in size be located?

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77085358/how-does-memory-account-for-different-occurrences-of-the-same-variable) before but it was clumsily formulated and I didn't get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

The list containing 2 elements takes up more space since you need to store both values instead of just one. In your example however the ids for `b[0]` and `b[1]` are the same because the values are the same thus python doesn't store them separately. If you tried it with different numbers you would get different ids.

Example:

```
b = [1,2]
print(id(b[0]))
print(id(b[1]))
```

Output:

```
140090491600648
140090491600680
```